col-span with style not working in tailwind css
I have 9 buttons with grid layout of grid-cols-2 so the last one remaining button will be left out as 1. I want that button to take the span of col 2 in tailwind
Code for .btn :
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

@layer components {
  .btns {
    @apply bg-black w-64 h-14 text-white;
  }
}

Code :
<div class="text-black text-62">
  <p>SHOP</p>
</div>

<div class="flex justify-around items-center">
  <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap-3">
    <button class="btns">TRULY WIRELESS EARBUDS</button>
    <button class="btns">PREMIUM TWS</button>
    <button class="btns">NEW TWS</button>
    <button class="btns">HEADPHONES</button>
    <button class="btns">GAMING</button>
    <button class="btns">EARBUDS</button>
    <button class="btns">DIME FAMILY</button>
    <button class="btns">BUDGET TWS</button>
    <button class="col-span-2 btns">ANC TWS</button>
  </div>
</div>

Styles work for all buttons but for the last button, when u Remove the style class of .btn and add col span, it works but when I use both, only style works not col-span, i'm sorry for my bad English..

Because in .btn you are defining width.
Change it to this for the last button:
.btns {
    @apply bg-black h-14 text-white;
}

